# tessnet c# giving wrong results

Tags: c#, ocr

i'm trying to run tessnet, the image contains only Numbers, but it always gives me "~" as a result, I don't understand why...
Here's the code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tessnet2.Tesseract ocr = new tessnet2.Tesseract();
            ocr.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789");
            ocr.Init(@"C:\Users\Poox\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\testCaptcha\tessdata", "fra", false);
            Bitmap imgBit = new Bitmap(getImage());
           //Changing the colors of the picutre, making it easier to read, number in black and a white background:
            Color good = new Color();
            good = imgBit.GetPixel(44, 19);//the color of the numbers
            int x = 0, y = 0, mx = 100, my = 42;
            for (x = 0; x < mx; x++)
            {
                for (y = 0; y < my; y++)
                {
                    if (imgBit.GetPixel(x, y).Equals(good))
                    {
                        //a number
                        imgBit.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Black);
                    }
                    else { imgBit.SetPixel(x, y, Color.White); }//the background
                }
            }
            imgBit.Save("image2.bmp");
            //OCR; 
            String captcha = "";
            List<tessnet2.Word> result = ocr.DoOCR(imgBit, Rectangle.Empty);
            imgBit.Dispose();
            foreach (tessnet2.Word word in result)
            {
                captcha = captcha + "" + word.Text;
            } MessageBox.Show(captcha);
       }

        public Image getImage()
        {
            Image img = null;
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            try
            {
                img = Image.FromStream(client.OpenRead("- Image Link - "));
            }catch { }
            client.Dispose();
            client = null;
            return img;
        }
```

I get the picture from the link, I make it more "CLEAR", and than I pass it to the OCR, but like I said, it doesn't read it correct, it gives me ~ as a result... Always! 
Here's what the picture looks like after I change the colors, to make it more visible: 
[Image](http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=351580image2.png)

What could be wrong with the code? How can I fix it?

Comment: It may be that your image is too small - OCR usually needs a decent level of resolution (most OCRd documents tend to be scans and therefore 300DPI or better). You might want to try rescaling the image to a few times the size (try 10 times bigger first) and see if that gives you any results.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, tried it, and it didn't work

Comment: Have you tried [training](http://blog.cedric.ws/how-to-train-tesseract-301) tesseract with your font?

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is related to what Charleh said in the comments. The image is too small. I took your image and resized it to 300x300 dpi and used interpolation (re-sample). Then I converted it to 1BPP since your original image was 32BPP using AutoBinarize and saved it out.

You can see the final image here:

[image: Processed image]